# Can the total energy of a solid be measured with photoemission?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Angle resolved photoemission spectroscopy (ARPES) is a really popular tool developed to study the behavior of solids by looking at the behavior of their photorlectrons. This is used to measure bandstructure most of the time as far as I understand.

The key quantity that comes out of  photoemission experiments is the momentum distribution of electrons living in the solid $n(\mathbf{k})$.

Assuming you have the momentum distribution, then you can calculate the kinetic energy simply through:

$$T=\int d\mathbf{k} \, n(\mathbf{k}) \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}$$

From there, one could apply the virial theorem to get the total energy, ($n=-1$ because Coulomb interactions drive most of the properties of solids, even magnetism)

$$2T=nU=-(T+V)$$

So it seems like photoemission can measure the total energy of any solid! In fact, since the integral to obtain $T$ doesn't care about the direction of $\mathbf{k}$, you don't need the angle resolved part of ARPES, just the energy resolution.

I looked through the literature and I couldn't find this idea used to give a number for the full energy of a solid,  so clearly this doesn't work in practice. My question is: **what is the most important reason this integral is impractical or inaccurate to compute from modern ARPES data?** I can think of a few, but am not familiar enough to the theory and practice to say which one.

1. Photoemission cannot be performed with the accuracy for usefully low error bars on $T$. Or the range of the measured $n(\mathbf{k})$ is limited, but I would guess you can fill in the details of core states with other techniques like XPS.
2. Photoemission does not truly measure $n(\mathbf{k})$ for some subtle reason in photoemission theory.
3. Photoemission cannot study the momentum direction perpendicular to the surface of the solid. (Although I've heard you can change the photon energy and still accomplish this. )

Comment: Well, for many crystals $E(k)$ is not a parabola, so that’s a problem...

Comment: In applying the virial theorem you seem to be assuming that each electron sees a single Coulomb potential, however electron actually interact with many atoms, and so do not experience a central potential. And that is before we consider the effect of electron-electron interactions.

Comment: @Jon Custer, the first principles Hamiltonian is still $H=\sum_i \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}\hat{c}_k^{\dagger} \hat{c}_k + \sum_{i,j} \frac{\rho_i(\mathbf{r}_i) \rho_j(\mathbf{r}_j)}{\vert \mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_i\vert}$. I'm not assuming any individual eigenstate has this form for their energy,  which as you point out is not correct. But this integral should still be valid to compute.

Comment: @By Symmetry, the virial theorem works for collections of bodies with mutual central potentials, that's the only way it can make sense in gravitationally bound systems of many particles for example.

Comment: If you don't know $E(k)$ for an eigenstate, you can't just integrate over them blindly and claim it is valid. It may be valid to compute the integral you suggest, it just doesn't have to have anything to do with the energy.

Comment: @Jon Custer, I must be missing something, but isn't the Hamiltonian I wrote correct? If so then the integral has everything to do with the total energy, it just doesn't have much to do with the Bloch wave basis you are referring to.

Comment: Yet as a crystal you need to be in the Bloch wave basis, and whether you are 'in' the basis or not $E$ vs $k$ does not have to look anything at all like a parabola as assumed in your integral.

Comment: @Jon Custer, thanks for the discussion, so are you saying the Hamiltonian I wrote above is incorrect?

Comment: @Jon Custer The Bloch wave picture relabels parts of the kinetic and potential energies of the first principles Hamiltonian as the kinetic energy of the new Bloch Hamiltonian, and throws out the e-e interactions (in the standard approach). That is what I mean by the Bloch basis. The integral in my question should be valid since it uses the very general first principles Hamiltonian and doesn't even assume crystallinity